# Is a given point P outside a given bounding box, in Ax < b form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-programming, constraints

Given a point $x$ and a bounding box $B$ - let's say we have the unit normals $N_i$ of the sides (pointing inwards) and one point on each side $P_i$ - we can check if $x$ is inside $B$ as follows:

$\forall{i}:(x - P_i)^T N_i > 0$

If, for use in quadratic programming, we want to write this constraint in the form of $Ax > b$ (let's say in 2D) we can write

$A = \begin{bmatrix} N_1 & N_2 \end{bmatrix},
\quad b = \begin{bmatrix} P_1^T N_1 \\ P_2^T N_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

This works for checking if a given point is *inside* a given bounding box.

If I want to constrain a given point to be *outside* of the bounding box, things seem to be more difficult. The problem is that the constraint is now as follows:

$\exists{i} : (x - P_i)^T N_i < 0.$

This change from a for-all operator to an exists-operator means I somehow have to write these constraints using an or-operator. Is there still some way for me to write these constraints in the form of $Ax > b$? Or should I look elsewhere entirely for solving a problem of this form?

Comment: Isn't the second problem just 'there exists no solution to the first problem'? If you can determine whenever $Ax>b$ has a solution then you should be able to determine when it doesn't, and then you are in the second case no?

Comment: Thomas, I'm not looking for a solution to Ax > b. I'm minimizing some other function f(x), with the constraint that Ax > b. In my case, to be more precise, I'm minimizing the norm of a translation vector to find the minimum translation of a point cloud such that none of the points lie in a given bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get the point but in my understanding your problem may be formulated as

$min ||d||_2 $

$ x_i -d \notin B, \quad \forall i=1,...,n$

that is minimizing a displacement $d$ such that a set of $n$ points $x_i$ in $R^k$ are outside a box

$B= \Pi_{j=1}^k [l_j,b_j]$

You can require also the points to be in a larger container if you want.
This is a not convex problem in general. Although a feasible solution may be easy to find, in general there are multiple local optima. Moreover, you cannot explicitly handle a $ \notin B$ constraints, unless you convert in a function that measure how much this constraint is violated.

I suggest you to look at this paper I published some years ago

Cassioli, Andrea, and Marco Locatelli. "A heuristic approach for packing identical rectangles in convex regions." Computers & Operations Research 38.9 (2011): 1342-1350.

In there you can find references and a way to measure the how deep a point is in a rectangle. Such measure can be used to define a constraint like $f(y)<=0$ that you can include in your optimization model with some tolerance:

$min ||d||_2 $

$ f(x_i -d) <=\epsilon, \quad \forall i=1,...,n$

It is still non convex but then you can apply local searches, heuristics or a deterministic global optimization method.

Note also that the case

$min ||d||_2 $

$ x_i -d \in B, \quad \forall i=1,...,n$

is a convex quadratic problem that does not need any quadratic term for the box inclusion. Any quadratic programming solver (as MOSEK, CPLEX,...) will handle directly in this form.